# Firefox developers edition network tab doesn't show local html resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

While studying routing in Angular JS, I have noticed that the network tab of the dev tools in firefox developer's edition browser only shows remote *.js resources pulled in but not local html and js resources while working on a locally hosted project. See comparison of the dev consoles between ffx dev ed and chrome in the screenshot, any way to resolve this?[image]

Comment: Side note: There's always the option to run a local server, which you will probably have to anyway at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a missing feature in the Firefox network monitor.  You can follow the bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1000540).